# How to compile and execute OpenCL kernel in Visual Studio using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, opencl

Basically I have a school assignment in which I have to write a function which takes in an OpenCL kernel (maybe as a byte buffer, or string), compiles it, executes it, in C#. I am having trouble with the concept of writing a C# function which can compile opencl kernel. Is there an example or links which can help me understand and write the function ?

I already have Intel opencl sdk and opencl.net integrated with my Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many ways to skin this cat, but one way is a .NET wrapper for OpenCL called [cloo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloo/).  I have an example project available for you to look at on [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/mplynch/fractalgen).

The gist is that cloo interfaces to the unmanaged OpenCL libraries.  You actually write your kernel in a string, and use cloo's API to compile and execute it.  Take a look at Julia.cs or Mandelbrot.cs in my repo.  There are methods in each called CreateGPU which will show you how to work with the API.

Comment: I went through Julia.cs. I think this is what I was looking for.